# conditional removal of macros

Tags: c++, c++11, c-preprocessor

I have codes like this:

```
    #define SUPPORTS_LOGGING

    class Logger {
        // ...
        template<typename... Args>
        void info(const char* fmt, const Args&... args) { /*...*/ }
        // ...
    };

    Logger logger_ {};

    void someMethod() {
#ifdef SUPPORTS_LOGGING
        logger_.info("....");
#endif
        //....
#ifdef SUPPORTS_LOGGING
        logger_.info("....");
#endif
    }
```

So, my problem is, logging code clutters main code, due to lot of `#ifdef`s. Can we remove `#ifdef`s in one line? Like:

```
LOG_INFO(logger_, info, "%d%d%d", a, b, c);
```

And above code conditionally expands to: `logger_.info("%d%d%d", a, b, c);` if `SUPPORTS_LOGGING` is defined.

Can we do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you can:

```
#ifdef SUPPORTS_LOGGING
  #define LOG_INFO(Logger, Info, ...) do { Logger.Info(__VA_ARGS__); } while (false)
#else
  #define LOG_INFO(Logger, Info, ...) do {} while (false)
#endif
```

This is similiar to how the standard macro `assert` is defined based on the presence/absence of macro `NDEBUG`.

Comment: Why not just make the `#else` expand to nothing?

Comment: @Barry I added it just by instinct ("always eat the semi-colon"), but it may help to catch forgotten `;` when compiling without `SUPPORTS_LOGGING`.